# retrieve data from views to html in template in django

Tags: django, django-views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse



mList=[
    {
        'id':1,'title':'ECOMMERCE WEBSITE','description':"ECOMMERCE IS GOOD"
    },{
        'id':2,'title':'Graphic WEBSITE','description':"graphic IS GOOD"
    },{
        'id':3,'title':'PORTFOLIO WEBSITE','description':"portfolio IS GOOD"
    },
]


def single(request,pk):
    projectObj = None
    for i in mList:
        if i['id'] == pk:
           projectObj = i
    return render(request,'appone/single-project.html', {'pobj': projectObj })
```

and in html in template folder I use:

```
<h1>    {{pobj.title}}--{{pobj.description}}</h1>
```

but nothing appears there:( whats the problem ? It should work fine

Comment: What urls are you query ? Normally `pk` must be in `[1, 2, 3]`. If not it will not work as expected since `projectObj = None`.

Comment: yes it is  1 or 2 or 3 as the id is 1,2,3.. still not showing in html

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).